# Get variable value by name from a String

Tags: javascript, php, server-side, var

This is for server side, regardless of client.

```
$data= file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
```

The `textfile.txt` contains

```
var obTemperature = "55";
var obIconCode = "01";
```

What can I enter so I can get `echo obTemperature` value of `55`?

is there not a simple php interface to read var values  by name?

please  no over complicated /half answers /trolling,

Comment: as an alternative, you can use json file instead, on your php side, just get the contents, json decode it and you're good to go

Comment: thank you tried that but over complicated on the results . . gave up .

Comment: well, whatever floats your boat, i'd do it that way though, `{"obTemperature" : "55", "obIconCode": "01"}`, just file get contents, json decode, and you have yourself your values and do what you want

Comment: php isn't javascript and doesn't parse javascript code nor does it run javascript code and they aren't compatible. You would need to treat the JS code as a string in php and try to use something like regular expressions to match the pattern. If you thought JSON was over complicated, a regex for this would be a thousand times worse.

Comment: You want to `echo` out `obTemperature` on the PHP side? Javascript runs *after* your PHP has finished running *inside* of the browser. PHP runs *before* Javascript *outside* of the browser. Are you certain you need to access a JS variable in your PHP code like that?

Comment: have no clue where to start.

Comment: assume the javascript is a text file and have   the varibles in it

Comment: i was had a textfile, it was simple, first line was color=blue next like was speed=50    i was able to echo color value and speed value with a command but could not remember how i did it .

Comment: @newuser0250 It sounds like you're approaching the problem from the wrong way. You *could* try to parse the JS file yourself from PHP but you're likely doing yourself a diservice. Forget *how* you're going to do it for a second and describe *what* you want to do.

Comment: Your problem: The values in the file aren't expressed in a way that is easily readable for PHP. Solution: **express the values in the file in a format that _is_ easily readable in any language of your choice.** Best candidate: JSON!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/var obTemperature = "(\d+)";/', $data, $match);
$temperature = $match[1];
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/qS6DYP)

Comment: echo $temperature; produced nothing thank you Barmar

Comment: I've added a demo showing that it works. If it's not working for you then the file doesn't contain what you said. Maybe the spaces aren't exactly as you showed? You can obviously tweak the regular expression to make it more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off explaining what you want to do in general, but if you are tied to this file format and the format is consistent:

```
$data = str_replace('var ', '$', $data);
eval($data);

echo $obTemperature;
echo $obIconCode;
```

However, any other types of JavaScript code will cause a parse error.

Also, you can treat it as an `ini` file:

```
$data = str_replace('var ', '', parse_ini_string($data));
echo $data['obTemperature'];
```

Or just:

```
$data = parse_ini_string($data);
echo $data['var obTemperature'];
```

Comment: thanks just trying to get values from file by name . .

Comment: once you eval($data) how does echo read from eval? .. thank you good answer

Comment: When you `eval` the variables are created for you to use.

Comment: thanks what if var obTemperature = "55" ( missing semicolon)   i tried $data = str_replace('"PHP_EOL', '";PHP_EOL', $data);  (also tried \n and r instead of php_Eol

Comment: You're going to have to have some consistency for anything to work.  For missing `;` replace `\n` with `;` or something. If the data is inconsistent nothing will work.